# vlc no gui from build

Tags: compiling, vlc

When I start VLC(installed version), I get output like the following in a Terminal window and then a new VLC player in graphical window:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower (revision 2.0.5-0-g1661b7d)
[0x9025908] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

When I start VLC from the bulid, I get the following output with no graphical window player appearing at all:

```
$ ./vlc
VLC media player 2.1.0-git Rincewind (revision 1.3.0-git-4793-g08223d4)
[0x88f6a40] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x8909d08] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.0-git Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

How do I start a new VLC gui window with the new build?  Are there any LUA dependencies I need to satisfy perhaps?

Comment: "vlc from the bulid" Could you eloborate a bit more on that? VLC 2.1.0 is not yet released... It seems you're running a prerelease.

Comment: does that really matter ......i guess my repositories got updated automatically............ by 'vlc from the build' i mean that i am using ./bootstrap ./configure and make to add modules and interfaces to the vlc(customization ) ...........do you any idea about getting the gui working ........or i should use vlc 2.0.5 (stable release) ??

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer :)